# Accessing servers on Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox where host is offline

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu VM running on VirtualBox and on this VM there are several servers running which I need to access from the host.

The host needs to be disconnected from any network (offline).

What kind of network do I define for this VM and how can I access it from the host - preferably through a fixed IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need a host-only network:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

First, be sure to create the network interface in the main VirtualBox interface:

```
File -> Preferences:
Network -> Host-only Networks
```

To access the network interfaces on the VM, the IP address range is typically, by default, in the range `192.168.56.100-254` (e.g. if you only have one VM, the address will be `192.168.56.101`).  But, you can check the exact address range, or change the range (and other settings), in the Host-only Networks configuration in the VBox UI above.

Or, if you're using Vagrant, use the network type "[private_network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html)", and no need to configure anything from the VBox UI.